# Why is the following progress bar not showing?

Tags: android-studio, progress-bar

What could be the issue with the layout? How do I make it show at the centre of either the second or the first Relative layout? I have tried all of them and still not showing.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

         //Some views here

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_header"
            android:background="#D8E5EE" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewAll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <Progressbar
            android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
             />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It should be ProgressBar instead of Progressbar ...

Comment: I may have edited that when writing the question. its definitely correct form on my code

Comment: Then please copy/paste the entire XML